# Referencing a table in a excel-formula that may or may not exist

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a formula in my VBA code that references a table that may or may not exist. I want an NA value to populate if it does not exist.

Formula: `= Index(myTable[Inventory], Match(1, ("Vans" = myTable[Brand])*("Shoes" = myTable[Product]),0))`

I'm tried the following:

1. `= IFERROR(Index(myTable[Inventory], Match(1, ("Vans" = myTable[Brand])*("Shoes" = myTable[Product]),0)), 'NA')`
2. `= IFERROR(Index(INDIRECT(myTable[Inventory]), Match(1, ("Vans" = INDIRECT( myTable[Brand]))*("Shoes" = INDIRECT(myTable[Product]),0))), 'NA')`

Comment: You will need to wrap the references in INDIRECT so they are strings.

Comment: Something like the following?
```= IFERROR(Index(INDIRECT(myTable[Inventory]), Match(1, ("Vans" = INDIRECT( myTable[Brand]))*("Shoes" = INDIRECT(myTable[Product]),0))), 'NA')```

Comment: What happened when you tried those formulas?  You would need `"NA"` and not `'NA'` though.

Comment: @TimWilliams It says there's a problem with this formula, then highlights the first occurrence of myTable in the Formula Bar.

Comment: @MJ - I think maybe `INDIRECT("myTable[Inventory]")` etc with quotes